# cannot execute binary file

Tags: binary, executable, ldd

I have a binary executable that's a part of an academic software package I've downloaded. I can't seem to get it to run, and I don't have access to the source code. I've tried the following things. Any thoughts?

Many thanks.

```
$ chmod +x random_cell
$ ./random_cell
-bash: ./random_cell: cannot execute binary file
$ file random_cell
random_cell: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, not stripped
$ ldd random_cell
random_cell: is not an object file
$ uname -m
x86_64
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and this is the answer I came up with

```
$ ~/opt/Linux-3.11.0-i686/svn/bin/svn --version
-bash: /home/fennellb/opt/Linux-3.11.0-i686/svn/bin/svn: cannot execute binary file

$ file ~/opt/Linux-3.11.0-i686/svn/bin/svn
/home/fennellb/opt/Linux-3.11.0-i686/svn/bin/svn: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=0x6b38ac5ac15af4334712b9bacc6646cabaefde9a, not stripped

$ find /bin /usr/bin -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | 
        xargs -0 file | 
        awk 'BEGIN           {c32=0;c64=0} 
             /ELF 64-bit/    {c64++} 
             /ELF 32-bit/    {c32++} 
             END             {print "ELF 32-bit count "c32; 
                              print "ELF 64-bit count "c64}'

ELF 32-bit count 1639
ELF 64-bit count 0
```

Well... that explains it!

Possible solutions: check to see if your CPU supports 64-bit Linux:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo  | egrep '^(model name|cpu MH|vend)'
cpu MHz         : 1200.000
model name      : Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  E2140  @ 1.60GHz
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
```

(then Google the exact CPU name to find its specifications)

Then upgrade to a 64-bit Linux (if you can) - [Download Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

One Alternative to run 64-bit code on 32-bit Linux is to use an true cpu emulator like qemu/bochs - [Bochs - OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bochs) - with a 64-bit Linux image (or VM like xen if your CPU supports it).

Another is to ask your software provider to recompile for 32-bit.

(For me I am going to recompile from source.)

Answer (score 0):

Note the output of your `file` command:

```
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked 
(uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, not stripped
```

That is saying the executable you're trying to run is compiled for the **x86-64** architecture. If  you're using a 32-bit operating system that won't run unless you recompile it for 32-bit.

Since you don't have the source code, I guess the easier solution would be to use a 64-bit Linux system to run it.

Comment: How do I tell if I'm running a 32 bit operating system? I think I should be on a 64 bit, but I'd be happy to check to be sure.

Comment: Oh.. wait. Now I see you used `uname -m` and it returned it is indeed a 64bit system: x86_64. Are you sure you set the execute bit on random_cell? Was it owned by your user?

Comment: I'm reasonably certain I've set the execute bit - $ ls -l random_cell
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 hippo  staff  1048235 Jul 24  2012 random_cell

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried executing it starting another shell? Like `sh random_cell`?

Comment: Oh. You don't have enough reputation yet to go into chat. Try running `strace random_cell`. It should output a great deal of info, but it will show all system calls happening till the execution finally fails, so we will certainly get come clues.

Comment: Unfortunately, strace doesn't seem to come with Mac (I'm running os 10.8.4). I did a little google-fu and found that people recommend 'dtruss' on mac; this is what I got :
$ sudo dtruss random_cell
dtrace: failed to execute random_cell: file is set-id or unreadable [Note: the '-c' option requires a full pathname to the file]

Comment: Hmm.. so you're on a MAC. I supposed you were using Linux. Maybe that's the problem... if this binary is for 64-bit Linux it might not run on MAC (the MAC OS kernel is based on BSD unix, if I'm not mistaken). Well, I might be wrong about how much binary incompatible they are, but you should check that, its probably the reason it doesn't work for you (see on `file` response: `for GNU/Linux 2.6.4`).